# What is the difference between sap.ui.core.routing.Router.navTo() and sap.m.routing.Targets.display()?

Tags: sapui5

Let’s say we I have one route and one target:

```
"routes": [{
  "pattern": "modify",
  "name": "modify",
  "target": [
    "master",
    "modify"
  ]
}],
"targets": {
  "modify": {
    "viewName": "Modify",
    "viewId": "modify",
    "viewLevel": 2
  }
}
```

So I can access the route by `this.getRouter().navTo("modify")`, meanwhile I can access the target by `this.getRouter().getTargets().display("modify")`. Both API can carry parameter by the second argument. It seems to achieve the same effect.

I can access target without defining a route for it. So I did not quite understand why I need a route?

Ref: [sap.m.routing.Targets](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.routing.Targets) and 
[sap.ui.core.routing.Router](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`display`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.48.5/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/routing/async/Target.js#L39) displays the target view without changing the hash value in contrast to [`navTo`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.48.5/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/routing/Router.js#L522).

You can find more information in the tutorial "[Display a Target Without Changing the Hash](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d9efab307ecc42b180b12cc8956e22d7)".

---

> Both API can carry parameter by the second argument. It seems to achieve the same effect.

- The *data* in `display` *method* is for the `display` *event* handler. When the event is [fired](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.48.5/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/routing/async/Target.js#L169), the handler carries the data we passed earlier.
- The *parameter map* we can pass to `navTo` is **mandatory if** the pattern actually awaits a parameter, e.g. if we've defined the pattern like this initially: `"pattern": "modify/{id}"`. Check out "[Navigate to Routes with Mandatory Parameters](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/f96d2522a5ca4382a274ae3c6d002ca0)".

Comment: Why insist to use source code in `async/Targets.js` instand of in `sync/Targets.js` ? It seems the default is sync? The [doc] says: "async defines Whether the views which are loaded within this router instance asyncly. The default value is set to false."

Comment: @Tina Since the `async` flag was introduced later, synchronous behavior had to stay as the default behavior due to the compatibility reasons (not to break existing applications). The current best practice (I'd say mandatory practice) is to enable asynchronous loading everywhere whenever possible. Since the [Walkthrough even uses the `async` flag](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e5200ee755f344c8aef8efcbab3308fb), we can assume that `async/Target.js` is the actual module that is, or is intended to be, used by application developers.

Comment: I am just wondering, is it possible not to loose oArguments when using display method? Because only `attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);` or similar seems to have reference to `oEvent.getParameter("arguments");`.

Answer (score 2):

Just complement [Boghyon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339793/5846045):

1. Route pattern is defined in Router, and hash is set in Router. That's the main difference.BTW, UI5 uses [crossroads](https://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/) and [hasher](https://github.com/millermedeiros/hasher/) to help implementing router.
2. `navTo()` in `sap.m.routing.Router` is borrowed from `sap.ui.core.routing.Router`
3. `display()` in `sap.m.routing.Targets` is borrowed from `sap.ui.core.routing.Targets`
4. in [_routeMatched](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/5469cc96fb092c0f71d2a0098ae1c0eb9dd2efe2/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/routing/async/Targets.js#L38) of Route, `oRouter._oTargets._display` is called. So [_display](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/7cc82f583755c4509cec94ab94f80dcb7f47eefc/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/routing/async/Route.js#L93) is called in both Router and Targets.
5. The parameter they use are different.`navTo` use Route name, and `display` use Target name. Sometimes they are defined the same.

   ```js
   onToPage2 : function () {
     // this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("pageRoute2");
     this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getTargets().display("pageTarget2");
   },

   onToPage1 : function () {
     this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("pageRoute1");
     // this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getTargets().display("pageTarget1");
   }
   ```