# Routing with Parameters - patternMatched Event Not Fired

Tags: sapui5

I am working on UI5 application using Web IDE and I have created a view where I need to bind the data based on parameter received from last view. But the `patternMatched` event is not firing.

#### manifest.json

```
"routing": {
  "config": {
    "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
    "viewType": "XML",
    "viewPath": "oomsdisplay.pso.com.view",
    "controlId": "app",
    "controlAggregation": "pages",
    "bypassed": {
      "target": ["notFound"]
    },
    "async": true
  },
  "routes": [{
    "pattern": "",
    "name": "worklist",
    "target": ["worklist"]
  }, {
    "pattern": "ZISOHSet/{objectId}",
    "name": "object",
     "target": ["object"]
  }, {
    "pattern": "ZISOHSet/{objectId}",
    "name": "payobject",
    "target": ["payobject"]
  }],
  "targets": {
    "worklist": {
      "viewName": "Worklist",
      "viewId": "worklist",
      "viewLevel": 1
    },
    "object": {
      "viewName": "Object",
      "viewId": "object",
      "viewLevel": 2
    },
    "objectNotFound": {
      "viewName": "ObjectNotFound",
      "viewId": "objectNotFound"
    },
    "notFound": {
      "viewName": "NotFound",
      "viewId": "notFound"
    },
    "payobject": {
      "viewName": "PayObject",
      "viewId": "payobject",
      "viewLevel": 2
    }
  }
}
```

#### Component.js

```
init: function() {
  UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
  // ...
  this.getRouter().initialize(); // create the views based on the url/hash
},
```

Now, I have created a view. When I press the button on view, my second view i.e. `PayObject` will be called. Here is my code on button press of view one:

```
fViewPayment: function(oEvent) {
  this.getRouter().getTargets().display("payobject", {
    objectId: "MyParameterhere"
  });
},
```

Now, here is my `PayObejct` view's init handler with object matched handler. But it is not working.

```
onInit: function() {
  // ...
  var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
  oRouter.getRoute("payobject").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
},

_onObjectMatched: function(oEvent) { // this event handler is not firing
  var sObjectId = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").objectId;
  sap.m.MessageBox.show(sObjectId);
  // ...
},
```

Comment: [fabiopagoti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48836054/5846045) should be right. The `patternMatched` event is only fired when the hash value has matched. What you did was, however, just displaying the view without changing any hash value. Use [`this.getRouter().navTo`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router/methods/navTo) instead. Related answer: [stackoverflow.com/a/46339793](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339793/5846045)

Comment: I replaced my code,
this.getRouter().navTo("payobject", {
     objectId: "0000000049"
   }, false);
but its still not calling oninit method, of next view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two routes with the same pattern, only the first one will be matched in the Router.

```
{
   "pattern": "ZISOHSet/{objectId}",
   "name": "object",
   "target": ["object"]
}, {
   "pattern": "ZISOHSet/{objectId}",
   "name": "payobject",
   "target": ["payobject"]
}
```

So in this case "object" will me matched. Change the patter of one of your routes and try again.

Furthermore, use navTo() when navigating:

```
this.getRouter().navTo("payobject", {
  objectId: "MyParameterhere"
});
```

Comment: super thanks,
"two routes with the same pattern, only the first one will be matched in the Router."
This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

getTargets().display

Use method navTo from your Router object

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router/overview

Comment: I replaced my code, as shown below,
this.getRouter().navTo("payobject", {
     objectId: "0000000049"
   }, false);

also still not calling, oninit object.

Comment: any idea @fabiopagoti, my page is navigating, but it is not firing view load events, not even object matched events

Comment: oninit should only be called once as soon as your view + controller is in memory. Router will never call onInit method of your target view's controller

Answer (score 1):

You have to routes with identical patterns: "object" and "payobject", I would try to remove one and check again.